# PrimeFaces Composite Components: commandLink doesn't work in dataTable

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

'

```
<cc:implementation>
<p:outputLabel value="#{cc}"/>
<p>  <p:commandButton value="Vedi lista file" actionListener="#{cc.researchFileInDirectory}" update="panelFileLog"/></p>  

<h:panelGrid id="panelFileLog">

    <p:dataTable var="file" rendered="#{cc.viewFileList}" binding="#{cc.listaFile}">
        <p:column headerText="File" style="width:100px">
            <h:outputText value="#{file.toString()}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Link" style="width:100px">        
            <p:commandLink id="downloadLink" value="download" ajax="false" actionListener="cc.downloadFile">
                <p:fileDownload value="#{cc.file}" />
            </p:commandLink>
        </p:column>

</p:dataTable>

</h:panelGrid>
</cc:implementation>'
```

This component is called in this page

```
  <l:logFile />
```

It loads the list of files but when I click on `commandLink`, it does not call the `actionListener` method but redirects me to the same page.

Comment: Post the xhtml for page hosting the control. Make sure you're in an `h:form` and that your backing beans are properly scoped and serialized.

Comment: yes it is in the h:form; i have not backing bean because logFile is composite components, it not needs the backing bean;

Answer (score 2):

Every component that uses `StreamedContent` does not work in a composite component. For more detailed explained, please read http://jsfcorner.blogspot.be/2012/11/advanced-primefaces-graphic-image.html . Since `<p:fileDownload/>` is one of them you can't use it.